# Unable to link GA4 property to Google Optimize

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I have a GA4 property set up in GA4 with a Web Stream configured and receiving data ("Receiving traffic in past 48 hours"). But, when I try to set up Google Optimize and link this property to it, the property appears disabled and when I click it says: "Unable to link this property. First create a web stream for this property within Analytics.", but I do have a Web Stream set up already!

[image: Google Optimize GA4 link error]

I have another UA property and this one I'm able to link, but I want to link the GA4 one.

I tried creating another Web Stream on my GA4 property and then this one appears to link on Google Optimize, but not the original one. What's going on? I don't want to go through the hassel of configuring a whole knew Web Stream just because of this.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I have the same issue. Not sure if anyone found a solve for it.

Comment: If you are using a Gsuite make sure your accounts are linked go to https://marketingplatform.google.com navigate to Administrator and Link the accounts

Answer (score 0):

You need to create data stream for the property within analytics before linking in google optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I used GA4 account created by Firebase for Web App. Had to switch to a normal GA4 account instead.